# Ansible job failed on localhost. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\"

Tags: ansible, localhost, ping

I am getting this error when I try to run my job template on a localhost:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: awx
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /usr/bin/ansible -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1683129872.0898027-1759605-51271684450430 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1683129872.0898027-1759605-51271684450430="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1683129872.0898027-1759605-51271684450430 `" ) && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1683080721.4434698-1739510-220849359042951 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1683080721.4434698-1739510-220849359042951=\"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1683080721.4434698-1739510-220849359042951 `\" ), exited with result 2", "unreachable": true}
```

Pinging localhost, " ansible localhost -m ping -i inventory.yml ", also results in the exact same error.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?